# Is this idea correct for the homotopy type of the punctured torus?

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

I am studying algebraic topology, and I want to find the fundamental group of the punctured torus. To do this, I looked at the square model of it and did a deformational retract onto the sides to get a hollow square model, like so:
[image: Punctured torus]

If we now think about the cell decomposition of this, this is simply 1 0 cell with 2 1 cells, where the boundary of each is simply sent to the 0 cell. This is the same thing as the wedge sum of $2$ circles, ${S^1\vee S^1}$, which has fundamental group ${\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z} = F_{2}}$. Hence the fundamental group of the punctured torus is ${F_2}$. Is this idea correct?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct idea.

Comment: @tangentbundle I see. Thank you! So if I had a space composed of 1 0-cell, and n 1-cells with each boundary being sent to the 0-cell, it's valid for me to say this is essentially just ${S^1}$ wedge summed with itself $n$ times?